# How to inject KafkaTemplate in Quarkus

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, microprofile

I'm trying to inject a `KafkaTemplate` to send a single message. I'm developing a small function that lies outside the reactive approach.

I can only find examples that use `@Ingoing` and `@Outgoing` from Smallrye but I don't need a `KafkaStream`.

I tried with Kafka-CDI but I'm unable to inject the `SimpleKafkaProducer`.

Any ideas?

**For Clement's answer**

It seems the right direction, but executing `orders.send("hello");` I receive this error:

```
(vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) Unhandled exception:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream not yet connected
```

I'm consuming from my topic by command line, Kafka is up and running, if I produce manually I can see the consumed messages.

It seems relative to this sentence by the doc:

> To use an Emitter for the stream hello, you need a @Incoming("hello")
>   somewhere in your code (or in your configuration).

I have this code in my class:

```
    @Incoming("orders")
    public CompletionStage<Void> consume(KafkaMessage<String, String> msg) {
        log.info("Received message (topic: {}, partition: {}) with key {}: {}", msg.getTopic(), msg.getPartition(), msg.getKey(), msg.getPayload());
        return msg.ack();
    }
```

Maybe I've forgotten some configurations?

Comment: What do you call `KafkaTemplate`?

Comment: I mean a KafkaProducer

Comment: Can you share your code? The IllegalStateException looks like a bug.
When are you emitting the item? On startup? Upon HTTP requests?

Comment: I was confusing topic's names and stream-names in application.properties. Now is working as expected. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you just need to use an `Emitter`:

```
@Inject
@Stream("orders") // Emit on the channel 'orders'
Emitter<String> orders;

// ...
orders.send("hello");
```

And in your `application.properties`, declare:

```
## Orders topic (WRITE)
mp.messaging.outgoing.orders.type=io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.Kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.orders.topic=orders
mp.messaging.outgoing.orders.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
mp.messaging.outgoing.orders.key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
mp.messaging.outgoing.orders.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
mp.messaging.outgoing.orders.acks=1
```

To avoid `Stream not yet connected` exception, as suggested by doc:

> To use an Emitter for the stream hello, you need a @Incoming("hello")
>   somewhere in your code (or in your configuration).

Assuming you have something like this in your application.properties:

```
# Orders topic (READ)
smallrye.messaging.source.orders-r-topic.type=io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.Kafka
smallrye.messaging.source.orders-r-topic.topic=orders
smallrye.messaging.source.orders-r-topic.bootstrap.servers=0.0.0.0:9092
smallrye.messaging.source.orders-r-topic.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
smallrye.messaging.source.orders-r-topic.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
smallrye.messaging.source.orders-r-topic.group.id=my-group-id
```

Add something like this:

```
@Incoming("orders-r-topic")
public CompletionStage<Void> consume(KafkaMessage<String, String> msg) {
    log.info("Received message (topic: {}, partition: {}) with key {}: {}", msg.getTopic(), msg.getPartition(), msg.getKey(), msg.getPayload());
    return msg.ack();
}
```

Comment: it seems the right direction but still not working. I've updated my question

Answer (score 3):

> Since [Clement's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220264/7773032) the [`@Stream`](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-reactive-messaging/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/smallrye/reactive/messaging/annotations/Stream.java) annotation has been deprecated. The [`@Channel`](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-reactive-messaging/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/smallrye/reactive/messaging/annotations/Channel.java) annotation
>   must be used instead.

You can use an `Emitter` provided by the `quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka` dependency to produce message to a Kafka topic.

A simple Kafka producer implementation:

```java
public class MyKafkaProducer {

    @Inject
    @Channel("my-topic")
    Emitter<String> myEmitter;

    public void produce(String message) {
      myEmitter.send(message);
    }
}
```

And the following configuration must be added to the application.properties file:

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.my-topic.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.my-topic.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
mp.messaging.outgoing.my-topic.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

This will produce string serialized messages to a kafka topic named `my-topic`.

Note that by default the name of the channel is also the name of the kafka topic in which the data will be produced. This behavior can be changed through the configuration. The supported configuration attributes are described in the reactive Messaging [documentation](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/#_forwarding_messages_to_kafka)